# I can never understand what case to use ever

Tags: dative, accusative

I can't figure it out, when to use akk and when to use Dativ for the life of me. There are the verbs that use one case but other than that I just can't understand. Why is it

> Ich habe etwas in die Wege geleitet?

> Ich habe in die Gruppe geschrieben?

> Augen auf die Straße halten?

> Einfluß auf meine Depression

Ich verstehe nicht, wie kann ich wissen, ob ich Dativ oder Akkusativ benutzen soll...

Comment: None of your sentences use Dativ case... und "Einfluss auf meine Depressionen" ist nichtmal ein Satz.

Comment: Do you know any rules (of thumb) when dative and accusative follow?

Comment: To clarify your question and pinpoint the specific issue: Are you struggling with the case required *by verbs, at large*, or *by verbs followed by prepositions*? (Your examples lean towards the latter sort, all include a preposition.) These are different questions and the answers might turn out differently.

Comment: I am struggling with the case required by verbs at large, because in my head I would say ich schreibe in der Gruppe. Why is the accusative used? What rules do I have to follow to figure it out?

Comment: The question that I have @planetmaker is why every sentence is with accusative?

Comment: I don't know any rules of thumb regarding dative and accusative. I used to only use dative because it would make sense in my head.... that's why I am trying to learn everything again the right way

Comment: Why is it " zeig Respekt an die Mama" und nicht "zeig Respekt an der mama"

Comment: Also I am very grateful for any non sarcastic passive aggressive comment thank you

Comment: Warum ist es "ich wünsche dir das beste auf deinem Weg" und nicht auf deinen weg?

Comment: This isn't something that you *understand* at all; it's something that must be learnt like irregular verbs forms are learnt.

Comment: Hi Alina! I have closed your question, because I think it is too broad. It is so general that an answer would require writing a section in a grammar book, I guess. If you have more specific questions about individual cases (pun intended), they will have a higher chance of being accepted and answered here.

Comment: What might be confusing is that there is no single general rule for using cases: sometimes they are required by a verb, sometimes they are determined by preposition, sometimes by whether we speak of motion or a static situation, etc.

Comment: As @marquinho mentioned in  his comment, all your examples have a preposition. So I think that the issue is not with verbs. In your question why "ich schreibe in die Gruppe" uses acc., it is because "in + acc" generally describes a direction. You might have guessed that from english "I write to the group", the "to + xxx" usually translates to a dative. Well, yes, it does, but then it is "Ich schreibe der Gruppe"

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule and it is said to be a good idea to learn which cases go with which verb for what purpose (but then, I'm a native speaker and I didn't have to think much about it).

Putting it generally and without claim for a comprehensive list nor being correct in all cases (there will be exceptions):
Dativ is used for:

- adverbials referring to a place:

  - Das Reh läuft *vom Feld* in den Wald.
  - Ich bewundere die Blumen *im Garten*
- the objects who somewhat passively are subject to the action:

  - Ich gebe *dem Hund* Futter
  - Du zeigst (den) Respekt *der Mama*
- some prepositions require (usually) Dativ: ab, aus, außer, bei, binnen, entgegen, gegenüber, gemäß, mit, (mit)samt, nach, seit, von, zu, zufolge, zuliebe

Akkusative is used for:

- the objects who are the object being manipulated or subjected to the action:

  - Ich gebe dem Hund *das Futter*
  - Ich bewundere *die Blumen* im Garten
- adverbials referring to a direction:

  - Das Reh läuft vom Feld *in den Wald*
- thes prepositions (usually) require Akkusativ: bis, durch, für, gegen, je, ohne, per, pro, um, via, wider

Mind: above is far from a complete list of prepositions. Many other can go with either case (possibly depending on intended meaning of the object), or it depends whether it preceeds or follows the object it refers to (e.g. 'entlang': Ich folge der Straße (Dativ) vs. Ich gehe die Straße entlang (Akkusativ)). There is a nice overview with examples [on this page](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Praposition) and it also notes when there are exceptions for some of the above noted prepositions.

Comment: Dank des Umstands, hier kommentieren zu können, möchte ich öffentlich bestreiten, daß "dank" den Dativ erfordert (sorry for writing that in German, but otherwise the pun wouldn't have worked). In fact, both "dank +Dativ" and "dank +Genitiv" is correct, see https://deutschlernerblog.de/dank-dem-oder-dank-des-dank-dativ-oder-genitiv/ and the same is IMHO true for "gemäß". (this little nitpick made me refrain from upvoting an otherwise great answer)

Comment: Ja, Du hast Recht. In der von mir verlinkten Quelle steht das auch als Anmerkung dazu, dass es gelegentlich auch mit Genitiv geht (und ja, dank dieser Anmerkung habe ich diese Präposition mal aus 'requires Dativ' herausgelöscht). Danke :)

Answer (score 0):

All your sentences contain a preposition:
*in* or *auf*.
These are prepositions related to a location (like über, unter, neben, hinter,vor)

All these prepositions may be used both with dative and accusative. The case changes the meaning:

With **accusative** you indicate a *direction* (wohin? worauf? ...). In English you would use into, onto (wheras other English prepositions like behind would not change)

*Ich habe in die Gruppe geschrieben.*

You have written something *directed to* the group.

**Dative** means a *location* (wo?). In English you use in and on.

*Ich habe in **der** Gruppe geschrieben.*

You have been in the group, writing something.

Your other examples do not really make sense with dative, thus an other example:

**Accusative:**

*Ein Vogel fliegt über **den** See*

A bird is flying, crossing the lake.

**Dative:**

*Ein Vogel fliegt über **dem** See*

A bird is flying above the surface of the lake.

No rules without exception:

*zu* and *von* are always with dative although they always indicate a direction.